# Postman returning "null" for Mongoose query

Tags: express, mongoose, postman, mern

I have a Mongoose `User` model that contains the field `username`. I have created a user with the username `bob97555x005`

In `users` router, I have the following route:

```
router.get("/check", (req, res, next) => {

  const query = String(req.body.username).toLowerCase();

  return User.findOne({ username: query })
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("no user found!");
    });
});
```

In Postman, I am hitting this route with:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/users/check?username=bob97555x005
```

This returns `null`. The expected behavior is returning the user json, which is in the database. Why am I getting the `null`?

P.S. There's nothing wrong with the router file setup itself, since I'm using it to create users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your using Http get method you should retrieve the passed parameter as **req.query.username**

```
const query = String(req.query.username).toLowerCase();
```

**Edit**

req.body is used when using the Http Post Method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that was a typo, sorry about that! The code is not working still, that wasn’t the issue.